# How to make a Stripe subscription status go from trialing to cancelled if there is no card?

Tags: stripe-payments

We let our customers do a 30 day free trial using Stripe subscriptions. We want the trial period to last exactly 30 days. If the subscription status is `trialing`, `active` or `past_due` then the customer can use our service.

If the customer has moved out of the trial period and has been paying and for some reason their card is no longer good then the subscription status goes from `active` to `past_due`. And the subscription status is `past_due` for 15 days (dictated by our retry settings). In other words, if they have been a paying customer and their card is not good when their monthly payment is due, then they can still use our service for an additional 15 days while they fix their card.

If the 30 day trial period ends and there is no card then the status moves from `trialing` to `active`. And then 3 minutes later the status goes from `active` to `past_due`. And then the status stays `past_due` for 15 days - essentially making the trial period 45 days. We don't want that; we want the trial period to only be 30 days.

How do we not allow those 15 extra days?

I would think that there would be a setting to make the subscription status go from `trialing` to `cancelled` in this situation so that it is easy to set the trial period length given the way we have it setup above. But this setting does not appear to exist.

So do I need to manually cancel the subscription when I detect(via webhook) the `trialing` to `active`, and then 3 minutes later `active` to `past_due`? I would store the datetime in my database when it goes from `trialing` to `active`. And then when it goes from `active` to `past_due`, I would check to see if that stored datatime was say less than 15 minutes ago - and if it is then I know I have a trial period that ended without a card and I cancel the subscription. Or is there a simpler way to do it?

Answer (score 5):

I was researching this myself. Turns out you can just set the `cancel_at` on creating a subscription using the same timestamp as your `trial_end`. When you receive a validated Payment Method from the user, you can remove the `cancel_at` timestamp by setting it to `null` so the subscription continues. Then just check if payments succeed and handle that properly.

So, if a user does not give you a Payment Method before the trial ends, then the subscription will get canceled at the `cancel_at` timestamp.

Comment: We would wait until the trial_will_end webhook (3 days before the end of the trial) and if they hadn't entered a card by then, THEN we would set the cancel_at. And of course, as soon as they added a payment we set it cancel_at to null. The problem comes if they have a card (from before) and wanted the trial to just end. Stripe really needs a property to indicate how a trial should transition after ending.

Answer (score 4):

The first solution would be to change the way you want failed payments for subscriptions to be handled. By default, when an invoice payment fails it is automatically retried after 3 days, then 5 days, then 7 days and then gets ultimately cancelled. You can definitely decide that the subscription needs to be cancelled after the first failed payment by changing the [settings](https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/recurring) in your dashboard.

The second solution is to catch the `invoice.payment_failed` in the webhook and immediately cancel the subscription on your end.

**EDIT**: Even if the customer does not have any active card associated and is now out of the trial period it should definitely be raised:

> Occurs whenever an invoice attempts to be paid, and the payment fails. This can occur either due to a declined payment, or because the customer has no active card. A particular case of note is that if a customer with no active card reaches the end of its free trial, an invoice.payment_failed notification will occur.

*EDIT 2*: If you want to know whether the trial just ended the easiest solution would be to save this on your end. You could just store when the customer subscribes to a plan and then detect whether this is the end of the trial based on the date when the `invoice.payment_failed` is received.

Comment: Regarding your first solution, I want to keep the multiple retries in place for customers that are not trailing, ie. customers that have already made a successful payment. I attempted to explain this in my second paragraph.

Comment: Disregard my first comment here. Regarding your first solution, I want to keep multiple retries in place for customers that are not trialing. Regarding your second solution, there never is an `invoice.payment_failed` event. There's just two `customer.subscription.updated` events. Then a `customer.updated` event. Then finally 15 days later the `customer.subscription.deleted` event.

Comment: That does not seem possible according to the documentation, I've just updated my answer

Comment: Ah yes, I see the `invoice.payment_failed` now. However, looking at the event data it doesn't seem like I can use that data alone to determine if the customer has just ended their trial period.

Comment: Updated my answer, there might be a way to detect this without saving it on your end but I can't think of one right now

Comment: but `invoice.payment_failed` might also be caused when the payment doesn't pan out for some reason the first time, although the 2nd time it can pan out.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way I can think of is to add a boolean `has_paid` attribute to your user model, which is only set to `true` when you receive an `invoice.payment_succeeded` webhook for an invoice whose `total` is greater than `0`. (When a trial begins, Stripe creates a $0 invoice for the trial period, which is always paid successfully, so you have to ignore that invoice.) Then your `invoice.payment_failed` webhook can cancel the subscription immediately if `has_paid` is false, or let the automatic retry cycle continue if `has_paid` is true.